# Quantum mechanics order of magnitudes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

**Is quantum mechanics totally irrelevant to the art of watch making? what are magnitudes of the physical parameters which characterize a "typical" wrist watch.**

Comment: This seems like a homework-type question to me.  You also need to clarify what you mean by a "wrist watch".  Many watches (for decades) use electronics and quartz watches have been around since the 1960's.  Also "irrelevant" at what remove, as making some modern materials may require the application of quantum theories.

Comment: What is a “typical” wrist watch?

Answer (score 2):

We start with a *mechanical* wristwatch.

Quantum mechanics is essential for its existence. Without QM, orbitals would not exist and all the electrons in an atom would spiral into the nucleus. Atoms as we know them would not exist; no atoms -> no metals -> no mechanical wristwatch.

Now, the electronic wristwatch.

The operation of the clock chip inside the watch relies on quantum processes in solids. No QM -> no semiconductors -> no electronic wristwatch.